# Dialog Fragments not showing sometimes while the code is being executed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have multiple dialog fragments in application. Time after time dialogs are not showing while the screen is becoming darker like it should when dialogs appear. Probelem is solved if I kill the application from task manager and open again. Interesting thing is that on Android 7.0+ problem does not occure. I have checked logs, everything is OK, code is being executed. Here is one of those dialog fragments:

```
/**
 * Created by yusufabd on 7/9/2017.
 */

public class DialogBankBranch extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, BankBranchView{

    @BindView(R.id.text_bank_title)
    TextView tvTitle;

    @BindView(R.id.text_value_manager)
    TextView tvManager;

    @BindView(R.id.text_value_phone)
    TextView tvPhone;

    @BindView(R.id.text_value_email)
    TextView tvEmail;

    @BindView(R.id.text_value_info)
    TextView tvInfo;

    private static final String ARG_BANK = "arg_bank";

    private BankDatum bank;
    private BankBranchPresenter presenter;

    public static void showDialog(Activity activity, String title, String msg){

        DialogBankBranch dialog = new DialogBankBranch();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);

        make(activity, dialog);

    }

    public static void showDialog(Activity activity, BankDatum bank){

        DialogBankBranch dialog = new DialogBankBranch();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(ARG_BANK, bank);
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);

        make(activity, dialog);

    }

    protected static void make(Activity activity, DialogFragment dialogFragment){
        if (activity != null){
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialogFragment.show(transaction, "");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null){
            bank = getArguments().getParcelable(ARG_BANK);
        }
        if (bank == null){
            showError(R.string.error_bank_data_not_found);
            getDialog().dismiss();
            return;
        }
        presenter = new BankBranchPresenter(this, bank);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map, container);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        tvTitle.setText(bank.getBranch());
        tvManager.setText(bank.getManager());
        tvPhone.setText(bank.getPhone());
        tvEmail.setText(bank.getEmail());
        tvEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvPhone.setOnClickListener(this);

        Spanned info = Html.fromHtml(LanguageUtil.isUzbek() ? bank.getInfoUzb() : bank.getInfo());
        tvInfo.setText(info);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        presenter.onClick(v.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Intent intent) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showError(String msg) {
        MyToast.show(msg);
    }

    public void showError(int msgId) {
        MyToast.show(msgId);
    }
}
```

How it looks when there is no bug: [image: No bug]

This bug: [image: Screen is a bit darkened, but dialog is not present]

What might be a reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating dialogFragment with fragmentManager while you are ought to use fragmentChildManager for nested fragments